# How can I find the intersection of two Django querysets?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I’ve got a Django model with two custom manager methods. Each returns a different subset of the model’s objects, based on a different property of the object.

```
class FeatureManager(models.Manager):

    def without_test_cases(self):
        return self.get_query_set().annotate(num_test_cases=models.Count('testcase_set')).filter(num_test_cases=0)

    def standardised(self):
        return self.get_query_set().annotate(standardised=Count('documentation_set__standard')).filter(standardised__gt=0)
```

(Both `testcase_set` and `documentation_set` refer to `ManyToManyField`s on other models.)

Is there any way to get a queryset, or just a list of objects, that’s the intersectiond of the querysets returned by each manager method?

Comment: What's stopping you from combining the two filter functions from each manager?

Comment: You mean like `Model.objects.managerMethodOne().managerMethodTwo()`? That didn’t seem to work. Maybe I didn’t write my manager method correctly?

Comment: The filter functions themselves.  `Model.objects.filter(this=that).filter(that=somethingelse)`.  Why aren't you doing that?

Comment: Ah! Yeah — both methods use sort of complex filters, they both have annotations in there.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: Can you provide some guidance on what makes these managers so complex?  Do they both support `get_query_set()`?  Is the `filter` entirely buried within the `get_query_set()` method?  What is the really issue that prevents you from simply chaining the filters?

Comment: Sure, I’ll just pop the code up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refactor

```
class FeatureManager(models.Manager):

    @staticmethod
    def _test_cases_eq_0( qs ):
       return qs.annotate( num_test_cases=models.Count('testcase_set') ).filter(num_test_cases=0)

    @staticmethod
    def _standardized_gt_0( qs ):
        return qs.annotate( standardised=Count('documentation_set__standard') ).filter(standardised__gt=0)

    def without_test_cases(self):
        return self._test_cases_eq_0( self.get_query_set() )

    def standardised(self):
        return self._standardized_gt_0( self.get_query_set() )

    def intersection( self ):
        return self._test_cases_eq_0( self._standardized_gt_0( self.get_query_set() ) )
```

Comment: Ah! Yeah that’s clever, I was thinking my design might be the problem.

Comment: Whether it fixes his problem or not, it still doesn't answer how to find the intersection of two querysets, to which this was the first link that google returned on a search for "django intersection of querysets"

Answer (score 75):

In most cases you can just write (exploiting the "Set" part of QuerySet) :

```
intersection = Model.objects.filter(...) & Model.objects.filter(...)
```

This isn't very well documented, but should behave almost exactly like using AND conditions on conditions from both queries. Relevant code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8c1/django/db/models/query.py#L203

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but it didn’t seem to work. I just seemed to get a queryset with all of the objects from the smaller queryset, including the ones that weren’t in the larger queryset.

Comment: Can you do the following: `intersection = Model.objects.filter(...) & Model.objects.filter(...)` and then `return HttpResponse("%s" % intersection.query)` That will make it easier to figure out what Django is doing when it combines the two queries into one.

Comment: You mention that this should work in "most" cases. Can you please also clarify in which cases it *won't* work?

Answer (score 28):

You can just do something like this:

```
intersection = queryset1 & queryset2
```

To do a union just replace `&` by `|`

Comment: Thanks, it works! but it does not work in sliced queryset

Answer (score 27):

As per Django 1.11, now it's available the function [intersection()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#intersection)

```
>>> qs1.intersection(qs2, qs3)
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe qs1.filter(pk__in=qs2) should work (usually). It seems to work for a similar case for me, it makes sense that it would work, and the generated query looks sane. (If one of your querysets uses values() to not select the primary key column or something weird, I can believe it'd break, though...)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it in python, not in the database:

```
intersection = set(queryset1) & set(queryset2)
```

The problems is that if you use different annotations in the queriesdue to the added annotations the objects might look different...

Comment: Is the answer of @lqc the same as yours(Are u sure the queries get evaluated and then intersected at the python level)? I mean based on Django's doc, we have only some special occasions that the query gets evaluated(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated). so if we want better performance, should we really use built-in functions like intersection() or union()? or it doesn't really matter?

Comment: I create a new question, I would be thankful if you answer my question, there -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/73597753/4417806

Answer (score 0):

One way may be to use the python sets module and just do an intersection:

make a couple of query sets that overlap at id=5:

```
In [42]: first = Location.objects.filter(id__lt=6)
In [43]: last = Location.objects.filter(id__gt=4)
```

"import sets" first (gets a deprecation warning... ummm... oh well). Now build and intersect them - we get one element in the set:

```
In [44]: sets.Set(first).intersection(sets.Set(last))
Out[44]: Set([<Location: Location object>])
```

Now get the id of the intersection elements to check it really is 5:

```
In [48]: [s.id for s in sets.Set(first).intersection(sets.Set(last))]
Out[48]: [5]
```

This obviously hits the database twice and returns all the elements of the query set - better way would be to chain the filters on your managers and that should be able to do it in one DB hit and at the SQL level. I cant see a QuerySet.and/or(QuerySet) method.

Comment: Don't ever use `sets`; it's deprecated, the builtin `set` (`frozenset` for immutable) is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you really are just using annotation to filter based on whether the count is zero or not, then this should work instead:

```
class FeatureManager(models.Manager):

    def without_test_cases(self):
        return self.get_query_set().filter(testcase__pk__isnull=True)

    def standardised(self):
        return self.get_query_set().filter(documentation_set__standard__isnull=False)
```

Since you no longer are worrying about annotation, the two queries should intersect very smoothly.

Comment: Ah, see, I don’t think that query for `standardised` works. That selects any Feature that has *one* related Documentation that *isn’t* a Standard — whereas I want it to select any Feature that has *no* related Documentations that *are* Standards.