# For making complex queries, Is it better to interact query_set like Sets or use built-in functions?

Tags: python, django, performance, django-queryset

I want to write a complex query that needs union and intersection. When I checked this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4411213/4417806), I found two approaches. So my need would be accomplished by

```
needed_keys = [A, B, C]
qs1 = model.objects.filter(entity=needed_keys[0])
for entity in needed_keys:
  qs1 = qs1 | model.objects.filter(entity=entity)
qs2 = qs2 & qs1
```

or

```
needed_keys = [A, B, C]
qs1 = model.objects.filter(entity=needed_keys[0])
for entity in needed_keys:
  qs1 = qs1.union(model.objects.filter(entity=entity))
qs2 = qs2.intersection(qs1)
```

based on [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4412014/4417806), It seems that the first approach will evaluate the result of the queries and then calculate the result of the AND or OR at the python level, Although I haven't seen anything about this evaluation in [Django's doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated). What will happen exactly?

To sum up, my questions are, Which approach is better? Is Django really evaluates 'model.objects.filter(entity=entity)' each time in the loop of the first approach?

P.S.

- please do not focus on the variable names or structure of the code, the goal was just to illustrate the situation.
- the type of 'entity' is textField, so I can't use 'model.objects.filter(entity__in=needed_keys)'
- when I checked the output of 'q2.query', the first approach was more readable for me but I want to be sure about its performance too.

Comment: It does evaluate the call to the `filter` function, yes. That doesn’t mean it makes any database query at that point. Querysets are always lazy and only interact with the actual database when the data is actually needed. This is well documented. Does that answer your question? Because I’m not sure what else you’re looking for…

Comment: @deceze So you mean in both approaches, we won't have any query to DB? that's cool. thanks for your clarification. About my second question, as the output of q2.query is different for each approach, which one of them is better?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion both you variants are wrong.
And is wrong too this sentence:

> the type of 'entity' is textField, so I can't use 'model.objects.filter(entity__in=needed_keys)'

`__in` works for strings too. That's why:

```
... # somethere in code
needed_filters = Q(entity__in = ['Adidas', 'Basidas', 'Cididas'])
... # somwhere else in code
needed_filters &= Q(other filter depends on your project)
... # at the end only one queryset creation
queryset = models.objects.filter(needed_filters)
# in your case: models.objects.filter(entity__in = ['Adidas', 'Basidas', 'Cididas'])
```

more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#in

Next step, you want to filter qs2. Why you don't do it directly instead of intersect:

```
qs2 = qs2.filter(pk__in = qs1.values_list('pk', flat=True))
```

Next step. Try start to works with query's into querysets, before ask into DB, not with data in querysets.
Otherwise you loose time on the `obj` creation, which you throw away with intersect:

```
query = Q(_connector=Q.OR, **{'entity':entity for entity in needed_keys})
qs2 = model.objects.filter(query_tocreate_qs2, query)  # your intersection
```

Once more time: if you do `intersect` for already created objects - you contaminate the function time.

Comment: tnx for ur answer, about the first part of your answer, using "__in", u are totally right, I could go that way and by doing so, the readability of code will be increased. About the second recommendation, using pk instead of intersection, that approach would work too but I think it maybe reduces the readability of the code. Additionally, as @deceze mentions in his comment, our query will be lazy so there wouldn't be any concern with it. To summarize my comment, your approach works great and it will solve my need but what if we had to OR two qs, which way is better, "q1|q2" or "q1.union(q2)"?

Comment: SQL compiler unpack queryset.pks, thats why here we dont need think about lazyness. SQL compiler made from q1|q2 - one queryset, without nested selects  in query. sql.union or sql.intersect - have more nested select in query. For my opinion -  queryset with '|' should be leighter for DB